# Баны и забаненные

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, блокировка

Как-то совсем скудно описана в справке «тёмная сторона Stack Overflow».

Мои вопросы относятся к блокировкам (банам) участников, вносивших и конструктивный вклад, а не спамеров, вандалов и иже с ними.

1. Какие разновидности банов применяются на русскоязычном Stack Overflow? К примеру, на час/неделю/бессрочный?
2. Не могли бы привести примеры действий пользователей с большой репутацией (хотя бы выше моей), за которые они были подвергнуты блокировке?
3. Удаляется ли автоматически не нарушающий правил проекта вклад заблокированного участника?

Answer (score 15):

Основные причины банов:

- агрессивное поведение по отношению к другим участникам,
- вандализм и самовандализм (встречается и у тех, кто тут не первый день),
- многократное игнорирование правил,
- ботоводство/накрутка голосов.

Меры:

1. Если конфликт еще только назревает, участник получает устное предупреждение. Далее следует бан на неделю/месяц/год за первое/второе/третье **серьезное** нарушение соответственно. Иногда может применяться бан менее недели.
2. Наиболее яркий случай - один из *pro tempore* модераторов был забанен за оскорбление
3. Не нарушающий правил контент не удаляется.

Кроме глобальных банов можно заработать запрет на правки (автоматически за многократно отклоненные правки и вручную за плагиат) и на проверки в очереди проверок (за вредительство).

Comment: А применяется ли амнистия в случае если заблокированный участник извинится и пообещает не повторять действия, приведшие к бану? К тем же «вандализму» и «самовандализму» опытные участники, как понимаю, прибегают, когда пребывают в явном ненастроении. Со всеми может случиться.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Амнистия наступает через неделю, когда заканчивается скрок блокировки.

Comment: @СашаЧерных оправдывать свои поступки плохим настроением - безответственно. У взрослого человека со здоровой психикой между эмоциями и действиями есть этап размышлений и принятия решения. Об этом хорошо написал Etki.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky или через год)

Answer (score 14):

Репутация участника никак (или почти никак) не влияет на решение о блокировке. Правила одинаковы для всех. Другое дело, что участники с опытом ещё ни разу не начинали, например,  публиковать спам. Помню один случай вандализма в собственных ответах - оказалось, что учетную запись угнали.

- Срок блокировки задается количеством дней. Это натуральное число, максимальное значение мне неизвестно, но видел 10 лет. Стандарт: неделя за первое серьезное нарушение, месяц за второе и год за третье.
- Лично я в последнее время банил двоих за оскорбления. Вообще это самое частое нарушение. Реже бывает: за накрутку голосов, за упорно некачественные вопросы, за массовый плагиат. При первом случае нарушений мы часто ограничиваемся  предупреждением.  Конкретных участников не покажу: нельзя, да и неуместно это.
- При блокировке может быть удалено только то содержимое, которое нарушает правила: сообщения и комментарии с оскорблениями, копипаста-плагиат и тому подобное.