# Перенос вопросов и ответов с Q&A сайтов, не относящихся к сети Stack Exchange, в частности, Toster

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, перенос-вопросов

### 1. Кратко

Есть желание перенести некоторые ответы (в особенности, те, которые писал сам, а не находил похожее в англоязычном интернете) с сайта [**Toster**](https://toster.ru/) на Stack Overfow на русском (далее также просто «Stack Overflow»). Спрашиваю здесь мнение, насколько сообщество считает это приемлемым.

---

### 2. Причина

Отнюдь не считаю себя великим писателем ответов, но я не Люблю что-то делать впустую. Большинство из Вас, мета-активных участников, провели далеко не один час за написанием сообщений. Представьте, каково Вам будет, если владельцы «наиграются», решат закрыть сайт, и Ваши труды и старания пропадут. И уж тем более в проигрыше окажутся те многие, которым Ваши ответы потенциально могут помочь.

Уже произошло закрытие крупных Q&A сайтов [**Яндекс.Ответы**](http://www.raskrutka.by/news/20530/) и [**Google Вопросы и Ответы**](https://geektimes.ru/post/224669/). На мой взгляд, больше шансов через год увидеть свои ответы в полном здравии на Stack Overflow, нежели Toster. Аргументы в следующем разделе.

---

### 3. Сравнение Stack Overflow vs Toster

Совершенно не склонен к идеализации Stack Overflow. Однако:

1. [**делаются дампы базы данных Stack Overflow**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2926/199934),
2. [**полезный вклад заблокированных участников не удаляется**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2950/199934),
3. [**удалённые со Stack Overflow сообщения сохраняются**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4036/19993),
4. [**в конце концов, можно скачать свой вклад**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209317/326972).

Не нашёл, чтобы на Toster было что-либо из вышеперечисленного. Исходя из этого есть основания предполагать, что в Stack Overflow

a. более ответственно относятся к вкладу пользователей,
b. если Stack Overflow решат прикрыть, будет кому продолжить дело,
c. действительно относятся к проекту как «базе знаний», чего нельзя сказать о Toster.

---

### 4. Авторские права

1. да, при переносе нужно указывать первоисточник и автора;
2. судя по [**данному обсуждению**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4614/199934), сообщество не возражает против цитирования материалов с других сайтов;
3. даже если условия лицензий сторонних сайтов не позволяют дословное цитирование, можно ведь и переписать материалы своими словами;
4. если говорить именно о Toster, не нашёл, под условиями какой лицензии пользователи оставляют вклад. Также не получается найти эту информацию на [**сайте ООО «Хабр»**](https://tmtm.ru/), которому принадлежит Toster, и на наиболее популярном из проектов ООО «Хабр» — [**Хабрахабре**](https://habrahabr.ru/info/agreement/).

---

### 5. Прочие проблемы

1. Возможно, некоторые пользователи посчитают перенос попыткой набить репутацию. Полагаю, что чужие сообщения [**необходимо помечать как общие**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4625/199934). Свои — не знаю, как решит сообщество.

---

### 6. Вопросы

Касаются переноса с любых Q&A сервисов:

1. Как сообщество относится к переносу в Stack Overflow на русском чужого вопроса/своего ответа на вопрос?
2. Как сообщество относится к переносу в Stack Overflow на русском чужого вопроса/чужого ответа на вопрос?

Comment: про лицензию хабра: https://habrahabr.ru/info/agreement/, пункты 4.8-4.10, осталось понять что это значит))

Comment: ну и можно задать вопрос на тостере под какой лицензией там контент)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, насколько понял, там написано, что с размещённым контентом имеет право делать сам Хабр, но не его пользователи. Спасибо.

Comment: "Пользователь гарантирует наличие права на распоряжение Контентом на условиях вышеуказанной лицензии в необходимом объеме.", то есть если я правильно понимаю птичий язык (не факт =), то автор решает сам под какой лицензией он написал, при условии что эта лицензия не противоречит предыдущим пунктам. То есть, можно ли цитировать конкретный пост-комментарий - надо уточнять у автора.

Comment: В правах предоставляемых хабру не написано ничего что позволяло бы ему преследовать за использование контента кем-то другим. Но опять же, я не юрист, могу ошибаться.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, была мысль спросить о лицензии там, но отказался от идеи. Напишут, что какая-то жёсткая, и любые варианты с переносом отпадут: ведь владельцам Тостера копирование от них невыгодно. Для меня же имеет значение не интересы владельцев SO или Хабра, а место, где ответы могут принести больше пользы. Спасибо.

Comment: В любом случае, имеет смысл выяснить значение лицензии хабра. Нам ведь не нужны юридические неприятности?

Comment: @СашаЧерных, я там нашел такой вопрос и да там ответили про жесткую лицензию (пункт 4.4. и 4.5 говорят ай яй яй так нельзя). Но. согласно пункту 4.8 хабр получает неисключительную лицензию на контент, так что если автор разрешает публиковать контент - то можно. При этом во избежание наверное лучше писать "не статья взята с хабра" а "статья автора икс, так же есть на хабре" =)

Comment: У меня есть опасения, что перенос контента с тостера вызовет межгалактическую агрессию, сопровождаемую карательными отрядами

Comment: @etki, не думаю, что явление массовый характер приобретёт. Спасибо.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Переноси. Уж на свои-то ответы у тебя точно права есть.

Comment: На ответы, допустим, есть. Но прав на чужие вопросы нет. Пусть там они зачастую и низкого качества вроде `У меня не работает $Плагин$. $Скриншот$`. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, вопросы с такими формулировками редко способствуют хорошему поиску. Можно ведь задать более хороший вопрос под свой ответ. Вот например, [дал ответ, неправильно поняв вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/605283/revisions) - так я его взял и отправил в [отдельный специально заданный вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/605310/178988).

Comment: Qwertiy, это да, см 4.3. Но если вопрос подлиннее и качественнее, неохота его переписывать. Спасибо.